# How to get data from this kind of rss on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, rss

How to get data from this kind of rss on ios ?

how to get data inside the `<![CDATA[ ?`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <title>Title 1</title>
        <link>http://link1.com</link>
        <description>Description 1</description>
        <language>en-us</language>
        <pubDate>Wed, 27 Feb 2013 12:38:54 EST</pubDate>
        <lastBuildDate>Wed, 27 Feb 2013 12:38:54 EST</lastBuildDate>
        <webMaster>webmaster@site.com (Hunny Bunny)</webMaster>

        <item>
        <title>item 1 title</title>
        <link>http://item1 link</link>

        <description><![CDATA[
            <h2>My Item 2</h2>
            <img src="http://itemi.com/image1.png" align="left"/>
        ]]></description>
        <pubDate>Wed, 27 Feb 2013 12:10:40 EST</pubDate>
        </item>

        <item>
        <title>item 2 title</title>
        <link>http://item2.com/link</link>

        <description><![CDATA[
            <h2>My Item 1</h2>
            <img src="http://itemi.com/image1.png" align="left"/>
        ]]></description>
        <pubDate>Wed, 27 Feb 2013 12:10:40 EST</pubDate>
        </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to use the [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  I've used it with great success when parsing my RSS as well as ATOM feeds.

To examine information within `<![CDATA[...]]>`, you'll want to implement the following method of the [NSXMLParserDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSXMLParserDelegate):

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
```

Here's a terrific tutorial to get you started: [Parsing XML data with NSXMLParser](http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser)

Comment: Thank You, I'll go through the tutorial.